# Should the LED be on the lens side of a light pipe, or the other way?

Tags: led, pcb, light

The image below is from a Bivar cutsheet.  I'm trying to figure out which end the led should be on.

[image: d]

Comment: Datasheet link, please. Side note: the \$60^\circ\$ outgoing angle I see is very close to the acceptance angle of quartz/glass. (Sapphire is twice that, by the way.)

Comment: I believe the LED typically goes on the flat side, since the rays from the LED are mostly normal to that surface they will passed through it with minimal reflection, and since they are nearly parallel with the pipe edges internal reflection will keep them from leaving the light pipe.

Comment: https://www.bivar.com/parts_content/Datasheets/PLPC1-XXX.pdf